# Oracle connection issue, when creating Content Data Store for Tridion 2009

Tags: content-delivery, 2009

I am creating content data store as Oracle for Tridion 2009. I have installed oracle databse Release 11.2.0.1.0. When i am executing tool DatabaseManager.exe, after entering the credentials for Tridion_sys user, error is coming as "connection failed, please review settings".I am not able to proceed with creation of database.

Can you please tell me what should be the possible reason and how can i solve this issue.

On tridion 2009 prerequisite manual , specified verion is Oracle 11g Database Release 1,Patch Set 11.1.0.7.

Comment: If your version of Oracle does not match the pre-requisites, then there's a very big chance it will NOT work... Oracle is quite picky about this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in Oracle installer - it doesn't register oraoledb11.dll. See [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2367179) and [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/9693681). Try registering it manually with regsvr32.

Otherwise, usual suspects: Did you install Oracle client? Is TNS Ping passing? Did you create Tridion_sys user using the script provided?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered these type of issues often, and it turns out to be a Oracle issue instead of SDL Tridion. Just check with a Oracle DBA if it has been installed and configured correctly and is accessible from the server where you are going to install the Tridion (or executing the DBManager utility). May be you can check whether you can established a connection with some sample application or utilities from the server.